# How to be sure if the files are uploaded in client side and show a message that files are successfully uploaded?

Tags: javascript, node.js, file, multer, uploading

I've built an express application which people can upload images to server (files are parsing by multer module). I want to send an alert that says "Files are successfully uploaded" when the files are uploaded. I don't want to redirect user and then show the alert.

I couldn't find any solution for that.

```js
    var express = require("express");
    var bodyParser = require("body-parser");
    var multer = require('multer');
    var app = express();

    app.use(bodyParser.json());

    var storage = multer.diskStorage({
        destination: function (req, file, callback) {
            callback(null, './images');
        },
        filename: function (req, file, callback) {
            callback(null, file.fieldname + '-' + Date.now() + ".jpg");
        }
    });

    var upload = multer({ storage: storage }).array('userPhoto', 5);

    app.get('/', function (req, res) {
        res.sendFile(__dirname + "/index.html");
    });

    app.post('/api/photo', function (req, res) {
        upload(req, res, function (err) {
            console.log(req.files)
        });
    });

    app.listen(3000, function () {
        console.log("Working on port 3000");
    });
```

```html
<html>
<head>
    <title>File upload Node. </title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="uploadForm" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="/api/photo" method="post">
        <input type="file" name="userPhoto" multiple />
        <button type="submit" value="Upload Image" name="submit"> Upload Image </button>
        <input type='text' id='random' name='random'><br>
        <span id="status"></span>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.